# Unlocking an Android phone

Tags: android, passwords, locking, adb, lockscreen

I forgot the password of my android phone (I have a Samsung A51) and I am trying to reset the lock password. It is important for me not to reset because I have important information that I want to obtain. I understand computers and Linux and less so on Android. The password is a drawing pattern and not a PIN and I tried through ADB it gave me problems because I don't have the USB Debugging mode so it's bugging me, I would really appreciate your help I have important information there

I tried to search for information on the internet and I also tried through software like dr.fone and it doesn't work because the model is not supported

Comment: This is a programming forum, it's not for general questions about phones - you'll have more luck asking on that kind of site. That said, the point of a password is to stop people without the password from accessing the device, and modern Android devices use various types of device encryption that mean they need to be unlocked before data can be read, so you might be out of luck here

Comment: This is a programming forum. If you have code that you would like to improve, please add it. Otherwise this might be a question for a different community, e.g. https://android.stackexchange.com/